# Why are properties not shown when using Object.create() and console.log()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

When I create an object using literal syntax, printing the object to the console shows the object `foo` and the `p` property.

```
foo = {};
foo.p = 42;
console.log(foo);
console.log(foo.p);

Outputs: 
{ p: 42 }
```

When I use Object.create() syntax, printing the object with console.log shows an empty object.

```
bar = Object.create({}, { p: { value: 42 } });
console.log(bar);
console.log(bar.p);

Outputs: 
{}
42
```

Why doesn't `bar` show the property `p` when using console.log()?

Comment: which browser are you using, it works fine in my chrome 49

Comment: What environment are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using NodeJS for these tests.

The reason is that in your second example (using `Object.create`), the `p` property is *non-enumerable*. When I run your examples on NodeJS, I don't see `p` in the second example because it's non-enumerable, since properties created via property descriptors such as the one in your second argument to `Object.create` default to non-enumerable unless you include `enumerable: true`. If I add `enumerable: true` to it, I see `p` in the second example, too.

What you see will vary depending on what environment you're using. For instance, in Chrome's devtools, I see `p` in both examples even when `p` isn't enumerable. But when outputting to a non-interactive console, I guess they decided to only show enumerable properties.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in console and its working fine.

[image]