# Creating usual object using Object.create?

Tags: javascript

```
let animal = {
    eats: true
  };
let rabbit = Object.create(animal, {
     jumps: {
     value: true, 
     writable: true,
     configurable: true 
    }
   });

console.log(rabbit.__proto__); // logs: {eats: true};
console.log(animal); // logs: {eats: true};
console.log(rabbit.jumps); // logs: true;
console.log(rabbit); // logs {}
```

The question is: if rabbit is empty for real, what happend? 
*animal* - has no *jumps* property 
*animal.**proto*** - has no *jumps* property 
*rabbit* - has no *jumps* property 
*rabbit.jumps* - is *true*

Comment: `rabbit` is *not* "empty for real". It does have one property, `jumps`, that you created. Sure, it's not enumerable, so the `console` in some environments won't log it, but it still exists. Also try `"jumps" in rabbit` and `rabbit.hasOwnProperty("jumps")`.

Comment: Did you check the actual console for the property - ie, SO text console doesnt show your `jumps` property but the chrome console does.

Comment: Don't rely too much on how the console represents objects. There is no standard for it, so it could show you whatever it wants. Whether it shows prototype properties or not is up to the console. It might not even tell you there is a prototype chain to examine. So, if `x.a` logs a value but `x` itself logs `{}` then you'd have to trust that the property with the value exists but just isn't shown as part of the object.

Comment: it's not copy object props it's inheriting from animal object ```console.log('abc', rabbit.abc); animal.abc = 123; console.log('abc', animal.abc); console.log('abc', rabbit.abc);```

Comment: Imho a better dupe: [Why are properties not shown when using Object.create() and console.log()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116946/why-are-properties-not-shown-when-using-object-create-and-console-log)

Comment: @Andreas Nice find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new property is not enumerable - if it were it would show up in a text-based console (Your original code shows up in an object-based console like chrome for example):

```js
const animal = {eats:true}

let rabbit = Object.create(animal, {
    jumps: {
      value: true, 
      writable: true,
      configurable: true ,
      enumerable:true
    }
  });

console.log(rabbit.__proto__); // logs: {eats: true};
console.log(animal); // logs: {eats: true};
console.log(rabbit.jumps); // logs: true;
console.log(rabbit); // logs as you expected
```

From the docs for [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties):

> **enumerable**
> true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. Defaults to false.

Comment: Why the answer? There are other questions (and answers) for that exact problem...

Comment: Thank you very much, my bad. 
But can we use "create" instead of "assign" to make object copies without any descriptors?

Comment: @Andreas I did look briefly before answering and couldnt find a good duplicate. I think the one Quentin found is OK. No harm no foul.